Avoid orphan sections less than N lines
From my understanding, widows and orphans are typically related to the first and last lines of paragraphs, not sections. However, when a new section starts at the bottom of a page, LaTeX seems to require a minimum of two lines before deciding to move the section to the next page. I want to configure the minimum number of lines allowed after the start of a section.
For example, in the Quisque ullamcorper section, there are only two lines on that page. It would be more reasonable to push this section to the next page, especially if this case appears on an odd page in twoside mode, to avoid the reader having to turn the page unnecessarily.

To solve this problem, I experimented with nowidow, but it doesn't address this issue. I found that needspace can solve it. By wrapping each section/subsection/subsubsection with this command:
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\pretocmd{\section}{%
\Needspace{12\baselineskip}%
}{}{}

I achieve the desired outcome, although I don't understand why the value 12 is needed to get 3 lines:

Is this solution acceptable?
Would there be a better alternative that I could use more transparently, such as:
\usepackage{lessorphans}
\setminparagraphlines{3}

This answer also uses \needspace but added manually before sections.
Also I discovered I asked a similar question in the past but got no answer. I may delete the other question though.
MRE
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{needspace}

\pretocmd{\section}{%
\Needspace{12\baselineskip}%
}{}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Lorem ipsum}

\Blindtext[2][1]

\section{Nuc vitae}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec turpis est, ultricies et nisi a, commodo aliquam turpis. Aliquam blandit ut risus in sodales. Pellentesque rhoncus gravida neque. Phasellus ac pellentesque libero, a varius mi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.

Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vivamus dapibus volutpat egestas. Nulla nec magna in odio ultricies sollicitudin. Mauris massa velit, tempus id rutrum vel, fermentum in neque. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed id augue dignissim, viverra ante et, scelerisque dolor.

Curabitur non faucibus risus. Quisque sapien felis, rhoncus et dictum quis, pulvinar at arcu. Duis augue orci, facilisis sed ipsum a, fringilla malesuada dolor.

\section{Quisque ullamcorper}

\Blindtext[3][1]

\end{document}


needspace is OK you need 12 or so as you are specifying needed space for: the spaces around the heading, the heading and the following text, not just the paragraph lines. Alternatively you want to adjust clubpenalties not widowpenalties and modify \@afterheading to use the e-tex \clubpenalties to specify multiple lines rather than the classic tex \clubpenalty

you have provided no example so I don't feel motivated to test any answer.

@DavidCarlisle Indeed, I forgot the example. I updated the question

If you use the hypothetical \setminparagraphlines{3} and a section begins with a 2-line paragraph followed by a 1-line paragraph, are you okay with a page break after either of the paragraphs, or only after the 1-line paragraph?

@MaxChernoff Good remark, I guess then it would not be \seminparagraphlines but more \setminorphansectionlinesatthebottomofapage. I don't know exactly what would be the proper typography name for this.

@nowox In that case, you'll probably want the \Needspace solution instead of the \clubpenalties solution since \clubpenalties doesn't affect page breaking between paragraphs.

\Needspace  is a reasonable solution as you proposed (plan 1)
These days it is better to add it to a command using a command hook rather than patching the command, so plan 2 is essentially the same solution just updated not to need an etoolbox patch.
To directly affect the paragaph breaking you need to set club penalties for the start of a paragraph not widow penalties (which control lines at the end).
LaTeX sets the classic TeX \clubpenalty to 10000 so preventing a page break after the first line. Here in plan 3 I replace that by the e-tex
\clubpenalties 2 10000 10000

so the no-page-break penalty is added after the first and second line so keeping three lines with section headings.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{needspace}

% plan 1
%\pretocmd{\section}{%
%\Needspace{12\baselineskip}%
%}{}{}

%  plan 2
%\AddToHook{cmd/section/before}{\Needspace{12\baselineskip}}

% plan 3
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@afterheading{\clubpenalty \@M}{\clubpenalties 2 \@M\@M}{\typeout{patched}}{\typeout{patch failed}} 
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\section{Lorem ipsum}

\Blindtext[2][1]

\section{Nuc vitae}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec turpis est, ultricies et nisi a, commodo aliquam turpis. Aliquam blandit ut risus in sodales. Pellentesque rhoncus gravida neque. Phasellus ac pellentesque libero, a varius mi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.

Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vivamus dapibus volutpat egestas. Nulla nec magna in odio ultricies sollicitudin. Mauris massa velit, tempus id rutrum vel, fermentum in neque. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed id augue dignissim, viverra ante et, scelerisque dolor.

Curabitur non faucibus risus. Quisque sapien felis, rhoncus et dictum quis, pulvinar at arcu. Duis augue orci, facilisis sed ipsum a, fringilla malesuada dolor.

\section{Quisque ullamcorper}

\Blindtext[3][1]

\end{document}


In plan 1 and 2 we have 12 for 3 lines, in plan 2 we have 2 10000 10000 (means 2 lines) perhaps 2 10000 10000 10000 three lines. Would it be reasonable to have a command that takes the number of lines and not some magic values?

@nowox well obviously you could make the 2 in plan 3 be an argument or (simpler) \sectionclublines  defined by \newcount\sectionclublines with a default of \sectionclublines=2  and then you need that many @M   assuming you want to forbid a page break or you could use say \clubpenalties 4 \@M \@M 5000 5000  which forbids a page break after line 1 and 2 and discourages but doesn't forbid it after lines three and four

@nowox for plan 1 and 2 specifying the length via 12\baselineskip is a bit odd really as it is not line based at all, it is a length so you are really using something like 4cm and saying that a section heading must be more than 4cm from the bottom of a page.

@nowox "2 10000 10000 (means 2 lines) "  no as I wrote in the answer that keeps three lines together. As it inserts two no-break penalties after the first line and after the second, so three lines are kept together.

Your last comment with the 4 \@M \@M 5000 5000 made me understand that. A gradient in the penalties is a good idea.
